# selenium suite in ruby/rspec - how to run multiple cases and stay logged in?

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec

I have a selenium suite in rspec.

How can I run multiple cases and keep the browser open and logged in between them?

I have a test suite in the selenium IDE that is comprised of about 20 unit cases.

I've exported both the individual test cases and the test suite file itself to ruby/rspec

I can run individual tests and they pass, e.g.

```
rspec spec/2day/units/set_QA_district_name_spec.rb
```

However when I tried to run the converted suite with either

```
rake spec
```

or

```
rspec spec/2day/complete_district_suite_spec.rb
```

it runs each spec one-by-one by bringing up (and then closing) the application for each test.

How can I run the suite and have the browser 'stay' up and logged in from test to test and not be opening and then closing down the browser window for each unit test that runs.

I have to run these tests in the standalone directory that I've created as they have to be kept separate from the rest of the applications test areas, in other words I have to avoid any use of rails itself.

I have set up the following Gemfile / spec_helper / Rake files in the root directory for these files as follows:

### Gemfile:

```
gem 'rspec'
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
```

### spec_runner.rb:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require 'rspec'
```

### Rakefile

```
require 'rspec'
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'
desc "Run all examples"
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t|
  t.ruby_opts = %w[-w]
  t.rspec_opts = %w[--color]
end
```

The contents of complete_district_suite.rb are:

```
ENV['RSPEC_COLOR'] = 'true'

require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),  "units/set_QA_district_name_spec.rb")
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),  "units/set_file_uploads_source_location_spec.rb")
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),  "units/district_spec.rb")
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),  "units/select_district_spec.rb")
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),  "units/upload_service_types_spec.rb")
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),  "units/upload_services_spec.rb")
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),  "units/upload_grades_spec.rb")
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),  "units/upload_schools_spec.rb")
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),  "units/upload_classrooms_spec.rb")
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),  "units/upload_students_spec.rb")
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),  "units/upload_ieps_spec.rb")
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),  "units/upload_travel_spec.rb")
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),  "units/manual_add_student_spec.rb")
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),  "units/generate_basic_schedule_spec.rb")
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),  "units/wait_for_dss_to_finish_spec.rb")
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),  "units/view_schedules_spec.rb")
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),  "units/visit_first_schedule_spec.rb")
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),  "units/monday_1pm_new_appt_spec.rb")
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),  "units/tuesday_2pm_new_5_students_spec.rb")
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),  "units/wednesday_9am_5pm_new_1_student_spec.rb")
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),  "units/thursday_9am_10am_new_1_manual_add_student_spec.rb")
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),  "units/friday_10am_11am_new_5_students_spec.rb")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `before(:all)`

```
describe "Search page" do
  before(:all) do
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new
  end

  it "should find all contacts" do
    ...
  end

  after(:all) do
    @browser.kill! rescue nil
  end
end
```

More info [here](http://old.rspec.info/documentation/before_and_after.html)

**Suggestion**

Also you could include all your spec files in one line by so :-

```
Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'units') + "/*_spec.rb"].each { |file|
            require file
}
```

Comment: +1 The one-liner require is good to know but my tests also do setup and need to be in a certain order (I know, bad dependency perhaps), so though I verified the one-liner works, just not right for me right now., Thx.

Comment: I wrapped all my requires with the before(:all) but it still does the close / open browser for each test.

Comment: You would need to place the command `@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox` command inside the before (:all). And the `@driver.quit` command inside after(:all). Also remove it from your individual tests.

Comment: I did both of those things and it still opens up a new window for each test.  I will probably post a new question with the updated details.